# Find point in multigeometry feature

Tags: r

How do I find out if there are points in a multi-geometry feature as I suspect it could cause the error, especially the second one? When using `ms_simplify` on `ms_simplify(drain[drain$H1 %in% unique(seq),], keep = 0.1)`, I get

```
Error: ms_simplify can only operate on (multi)polygons and (multi)linestrings
```

If I remove the `%in%` and subset with `>`, `=`, `<` signs it works. Also, the geometry column is labelled `Shape` for some reason and not `geom` as usually and is loaded from a `.gpkg` file drain `st_read("water.gpkg")`. ***Does anyone have ideas why these problems arise?***

My code is quite long and I assume the error is specific to the data that I have. Therefore, no reproducible example this time :/

Comment: What package does the `ms_simplify` function come from?

Comment: Where does the `>=<` operator come from?

Comment: 1st comment: ```ms_simplify``` is from the library ```rmapshaper``` and has the advantage of preserving the topology even when the simplification is large

Comment: 2nd Comment: edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reproducible examples can be constructed from simple examples. Let's make a data frame with a geometry collection, a point, and a polygon:

```
> g1 = st_geometrycollection(list(st_point(c(0,0)),st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,1,1,0))))))
> g2 = st_point(c(1,1))
> g3 = st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,1,1,0))))
```

That's the three geometry elements which we make into a vector column in the data frame:

```
> d = st_as_sf(data.frame(x=1:3,geom=st_sfc(g1,g2,g3)))
```

To get the geometry type of each row back, use `st_geometry_type`:

```
> st_geometry_type(st_geometry(d))
[1] GEOMETRYCOLLECTION POINT              POLYGON           
18 Levels: GEOMETRY POINT LINESTRING POLYGON MULTIPOINT ... TRIANGLE
```

That tells you which rows are `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` types, and then you can inspect them for their constituent types. We saw above that the first element is a collection, so lets' look at element `[[1]]` of the geometry. We use `sapply` to run `st_geometry_type` on each element of the collection:

```
> sapply(st_geometry(d)[[1]],st_geometry_type)
[1] POINT   POLYGON
18 Levels: GEOMETRY POINT LINESTRING POLYGON MULTIPOINT ... TRIANGLE
```

You could then test if any of that returned value is `POINT` or not `POLYGON`, according to your application.

Don't try this on every element though, since it errors for non collections:

```
> sapply(st_geometry(d)[[2]],st_geometry_type)
Error in UseMethod("st_geometry") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_geometry' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

so first test a thing is a collection before running an `sapply` over its elements with `st_geometry_type`.

Geometry column names are arbitrary and its only convention that names them `geom` or `geometry`. Your geopackage uses `Shape` and there's no reason why that should be a problem with any software - using `st_geometry(data)` should always extract the geometry column from an `sf` data frame, whatever its name is.

Comment: Thank you so much Spacedman. Your answers are so helpful! In fact, when dropping the the ```POINT``` and the ```GEOMETRYCOLLECTION```, I can plot, use ```ms_simplify()```. ```st_geometry_type(st_geometry(d))``` is exactly what I was looking for.